# Tkinter - Changing Label with Function

Tags: function, tkinter, label

I want to overwrite/replace the text Label with a button.
If I try to make a new label and place it at the same location, the previous text is still visable since it is longer than the new text.
Is it possible to delete the previous text first? any hints

```
root = tk.Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

def changetext():
        labeltest = Label(tab1, text="short text").place(x=20, y=20)

labeltest = Label(tab1, text="long long long text").place(x=20, y=20)

button1 = Button(tab1, text="Change text pls", command=changetext)
button1.place(x=20, y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to delete the label.  Just use `labeltest.config(text="short text")` to update the label inside `changetext()`.

Comment: Right now you have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) problem with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) mistake. You shouldn't define a widget and `pack`/`place`/`grid` it on the same line. It's bad practise and you loose the reference to that widget. And as @acw1668 pointed out you can use `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=<new text>)` like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def changetext():
        labeltest.config(text="short text")

root = tk.Tk()

labeltest = tk.Label(root, text="long long long text")
labeltest.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Change text pls", command=changetext)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is the error message I get:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: @caarloXY As I said in the first sentence from my answer: *Your code has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) mistake.* You should split the `.place(...)` in a new line.